# Set base URL of Windows Phone 8.1 WebView and use NavigateToString()

Tags: c#, iframe, webview, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

In my app I want to load an html that contains an **iframe** with a remote url. This html is always the same, except for the iframe's src. What I do is hold the **html in a string**, and fill in the iframe url, than call **NavigateToString(html)**. I get the **iframe url** from a REST API. I also get a **baseUrl**. If I **merge those two urls** into an absoulute url and set that as the iframe's src, the **page won't load** due to security reasons (it's a payment page). But if I set it **without baseUrl**, of course, the webview has no idea what's the baseUrl is, and **the page** also **won't load**.

In Android one could simply call *webView.loadDataWithBaseURL*. Is there something like this in Windows Phone 8.1? Any workaround?

(The problem is further complicated by that I also have to set Cookies to the webview.)

Comment: I came up with a solution but it's a hack: I use NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage to load a not existing url (thus setting the base Url), than replace the whole html content with JavaScript to the html containing the iframe. Other ideas welcome though!

Comment: can you share code blocks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came up with a solution, which works, and actually it's less hacky than it seemed to me at first.

I skipped NavigateToString. By using NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage, I can send a request to an URL, for example http://mybackend.com. I can set cookies as well (more information on this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a451d411-9312-4d40-80ee-112e166144ab/how-to-send-auth-cookie-in-webview-request?forum=winappswithcsharp). So far I have:

1. base URL set
2. cookies set.

Though, I haven't set my local html string yet. For this, in the WebView's NavigationCompleted event, I run a JS script like this:

```
await wvSecurePay.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML = '" + htmlToLoad + "';"})
```

This will replace the current html content with the one I want to load. So I have my html containing the iframe with the relative url on a page which has the domain I need.